# Is it possible to get a critical hit/kill with a grenade?

Tags: destiny

I think that it is possible if you use the Swarm Grenade, but I'm not sure.

Can someone else confirm if this is possible?

Comment: Fun fact: you can deal some damage with a grenade throw before it even explodes, but it doesn't crit even on headshot. See [Destiny Mythbusters episode 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELFlJNqvwPs), it's in the very beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why yes it is very possible, but only on Devil Walkers and Tanks and other things that require separate Object Breaks(Legs).  Anything else considers Grenades as an AoE non crit effect.

Comment: What about if you use the Swarm Grenade? I only ask about this specifically because I've seen it be blocked by the Cabal Phalanx's shield.

Comment: Phalanx shield tend to block everything.  Including rocket launchers and pulse grenades.

Comment: I recon you can also get a critical hit by hitting an enemy in their weak spot with direct impact? (Only with grenades that does not explode on impact.)